# Property of the set of subsequential limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $s_n$ be a bound real sequence and
$$E:= \{ s \in \mathbb R: \exists \text{ subsequence }s_{n_i} \text{ s.t. }s_{n_i} \to s \}$$
I want to show the following: $s \in E$ iff $\forall \epsilon >0$ the set $\{n \in \mathbb N :|s_n-s|\leq \epsilon \}$ is infinite.

Here is my attempt: Suppose $s \in E$, then there exist a subsequence $s_{n_i}$, s.t. $s_{n_i} \to s \in \mathbb R$. But this means, that $\forall \epsilon >0$, there exist $N \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $\forall n \geq N$ we have that $|s_{n_i}-s|\leq \epsilon$ (which mean that $\{n \in \mathbb N: |s_{n_i}-s| \leq \epsilon\}$ is infinite). But now since $(s_{n_i}) \subseteq (s_n))$ the statement follows.

For the other direction, suppose that for fixed $\epsilon >0$ the set $\{n \in \mathbb N :|s_n-s|\leq \epsilon \}$ is infinite. This means that $s \in E$, since the sequence $s_n$ converges to $s$ and one can take as subsequence $s_n$ itself.

Is my attempt right? Many thanks for some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

your first proof seems good, but your second proof is incorrect, a subset of $\mathbb{N} $ being infinite, doesn't necessarily means that it has the property, whenever it contains a number, it contains all of its successors,moreover if the set is infinite for some $\epsilon$ it doesn't mean it is infinite for another:Consider $s_{n} =(-1)^{n}$,then $\{n\in \mathbb{N} \backslash \lvert s_{n} - 1 \rvert <1 \} $ is infinite, but $s_{n} $ doesn't converge to 1.
Try to construct a subsequence converging to $s$, let $n_{k}=\min \{n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{n_{1},\cdots n_{k-1}\} \backslash \lvert s_{n} - s\rvert \ \leq \frac{1}{k} \}$,then $s_{n_{k}}$ is a subsequence converging to $s$.the choice is possible since for every $\epsilon$, the set defined above is infinite hence non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is correct, except that you wrote $A$ instead of $E$.

The other one is wrong. The fact that the set $\{n\in\Bbb N:|s_n-s|\leqslant\varepsilon\}$ is finite does *not* imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=s$. If that set is infinite for every $\varepsilon>0$, take $n_1\in\Bbb N$ such that $|s_{n_1}-s|<1$. Then take $n_2>n_1$ such that $|s_{n_3}-s|<\frac12$. Then take $n_3>n_2$ such that $|s_{n_3}-s|<\frac13$.  And so on. Then $s=\lim_{k\to\infty}s_{n_k}$.